# How to find the minimum value for 1-many relationship?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to find the minimum date value in a list of transactions that are associated with an investment. There are many transactions for one investment, clearly. How do I write this so that Progress will only give me the minimum transaction date? I get the minimum at the end of my list, but I do not want the list, just the minimum value.

```
FOR EACH ilinvest WHERE ilinvest.inv-num EQ 406885:
    FOR EACH iltrans WHERE iltrans.reg-pin EQ ilinvest.reg-pin:
        DISPLAY iltrans.tran-dt(MINIMUM).
    END.
END.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an index on the `tran-dt` field, you could do something like

```
FOR EACH ilinvest WHERE ilinvest.inv-num EQ 406885:
    FOR EACH iltrans WHERE iltrans.reg-pin EQ ilinvest.reg-pin
          BY iltrans.tran-dt ASCENDING:
        // The iltrans.tran-dt value here is the lowest. Note that
        // you may see the unknown value .
        // Leave after getting the first record
        LEAVE.
    END.
END.
```

Comment: It appears in my data dictionary that there is an index on tran-dt field, but I get an error on this syntax of invalid FOR, DO, REPEAT, or EDITING. Do I need to explicitly state that I am using the index?

Comment: Ascending does not belong there, https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-essentials-117/page/Sorting-records-by-using-the-BY-phrase.html

Comment: Then what is the syntax for getting the minimum? I like the idea of using ascending and then leaving the loop.

Comment: Just remove ascending...

Comment: I always forget that it's ASCENDING by default, and you have to add DESCENDING

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help. Removing the ascending worked like a charm:

```
FOR EACH ilinvest: 
    FOR EACH iltrans WHERE iltrans.reg-pin EQ ilinvest.reg-pin 
        AND iltrans.acct-num EQ ilinvest.inv-num 
          BY iltrans.tran-dt:
          iMin = iltrans.tran-dt.
        LEAVE.
    END.
END.
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware if your date field has no value, ie the unknown value (`?`). If the unknown value sorts before or after other values depends on all sorts of black magic

Additionally, since I do not like `leave`, I prefer a `while`:

```
def var dt min as date no-undo.

for each ilinvest no-lock,
each iltrans 
   where iltrans.reg-pin  = ilinvest.reg-pin 
   and   iltrans.acct-num = ilinvest.inv-num  
no-lock
   by iltrans.tran-dt
while dtmin = ?:

   if iltrans.trans-dt <> ? then
      dtmin = iltrans.tran-dt.

end.
```

Comment: LEAVE left me a bit uncomfortable, too, so thanks for sending.

Comment: The implicit requirement here is that you want an actual/real date. This code gets you the actual 'real' first date, but it may not be the first record in that result set.

Comment: You can also probably remove the `IF <> ?` check, and just assign the value, since the WHILE will do the needful.